# Read ZipFile from URL into StringIO and parse with panda.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, stringio, python-zipfile

I'm trying to read `ZipFile` data from a URL and via `StringIO` parse the data inside the `ZipFile` as csv using `pandas.read_csv`

```
r = req.get("http://seanlahman.com/files/database/lahman-csv_2014-02-14.zip").content
file = ZipFile(StringIO(r))
salaries_csv = file.open("Salaries.csv")
salaries = pd.read_csv(salaries_csv)
```

The last line gave me an error:

```
CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Calling read(nbytes) on source failed. Try engine='python'.
```

However if i try using

```
salaries = pd.read_csv(file.open("Salaries.csv"))
```

it works.

So I was wondering what am I missing out here.

`file.open` should return a `ZipExtFile` object and since read_csv takes only string or file handle / `StringIO` input, why is the last line working then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something is wrong with the way you read the data, it works for me using urllib2.

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
from StringIO import StringIO
import urllib2

r = urllib2.urlopen("http://seanlahman.com/files/database/lahman-csv_2014-02-14.zip").read()
file = ZipFile(StringIO(r))
salaries_csv = file.open("Salaries.csv")
salaries = pd.read_csv(salaries_csv)
       yearID teamID lgID   playerID    salary
0        1985    BAL   AL  murraed02   1472819
1        1985    BAL   AL   lynnfr01   1090000
2        1985    BAL   AL  ripkeca01    800000
3        1985    BAL   AL   lacyle01    725000
4        1985    BAL   AL  flanami01    641667
5        1985    BAL   AL  boddimi01    625000
6        1985    BAL   AL  stewasa01    581250
7        1985    BAL   AL  martide01    560000
```

Answer (score 6):

Few changes for Python 3.5 to @firelynx's answer

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
from io import BytesIO
import urllib.request as urllib2

r = urllib2.urlopen("http://seanlahman.com/files/database/lahman-csv_2014-02-14.zip").read()
file = ZipFile(BytesIO(r))
salaries_csv = file.open("Salaries.csv")
salaries = pd.read_csv(salaries_csv)
print (salaries)
```