# Read specific csv file from zip using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a data I am interested in.

http://fenixservices.fao.org/faostat/static/bulkdownloads/Production_Crops_E_All_Data.zip

It consists of 3 files:

[image]

I want to download zip with pandas and create DataFrame from 1 file called Production_Crops_E_All_Data.csv

```
import pandas as pd
url="http://fenixservices.fao.org/faostat/static/bulkdownloads/Production_Crops_E_All_Data.zip"
df=pd.read_csv(url)
```

Pandas can download files, it can work with zips and of course it can work with csv files. But how can I work with 1 specific file in archive with many files?

Now I get error

ValueError: ('Multiple files found in compressed zip file %s)

This post doesn't answer my question bcause I have multiple files in 1 zip
[Read a zipped file as a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18885175/read-a-zipped-file-as-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read a zipped file as a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18885175/read-a-zipped-file-as-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: @Pasindu Gamarachchi no, the link you pointed to works well when the zip file contains only a single file, but the OP is talking about multiple files contained in a single zip file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31967635/read-zipfile-from-url-into-stringio-and-parse-with-panda-read-csv)

try this

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
import io
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pandas as pd

r = urlopen("http://fenixservices.fao.org/faostat/static/bulkdownloads/Production_Crops_E_All_Data.zip").read()
file = ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r))
data_df = pd.read_csv(file.open("Production_Crops_E_All_Data.csv"), encoding='latin1')
data_df_noflags = pd.read_csv(file.open("Production_Crops_E_All_Data_NOFLAG.csv"), encoding='latin1')
data_df_flags = pd.read_csv(file.open("Production_Crops_E_Flags.csv"), encoding='latin1')
```

Hope this helps!
EDIT: updated for python3 StringIO to io.StringIO

EDIT: updated the import of urllib, changed usage of StringIO to BytesIO. Also your CSV files are not utf-8 encoding, I tried latin1 and that worked.

Comment: import urllib should be edited to import urllib.request.

Comment: file = ZipFile(io.StringIO(r)) traceback: TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes

Comment: Thank you for updating the post but error 'TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes' still exists. ////  .read().decode('utf8') doesn't help

Comment: Hey @IgorK.Updated the answer to fix that, please use BytesIO instead of StringIO

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You could use python's [datatable](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/start/install.html), which is a reimplementation of [Rdatatable](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/) in python.

Read in data :

```
from datatable import fread

#The exact file to be extracted is known, simply append it to the zip name:
 url = "Production_Crops_E_All_Data.zip/Production_Crops_E_All_Data.csv"

 df = fread(url)

#convert to pandas

 df.to_pandas()
```

You can equally work within datatable; do note however, that it is not as feature-rich as Pandas; but it is a powerful and very fast tool.

Update: You can use the [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) module as well :

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
from io import BytesIO

with ZipFile(url) as myzip:
    with myzip.open("Production_Crops_E_All_Data.csv") as myfile:
        data = myfile.read()

#read data into pandas
#had to toy a bit with the encoding,
#thankfully it is a known issue on SO
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/51843284/7175713
df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(data), encoding="iso-8859-1", low_memory=False)
```

Comment: for pity I cannot install this library using pip install.  "SystemExit: Suitable C++ compiler cannot be determined. Please specify a compiler executable in the `CXX` environment variable."